# Manage a Gmail Setting through google admin sdk

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I searched on the Web to find an evidence for changing Gmail settings through google admin sdk but I could not find anything!
I want to add labels to a gmail account(x@gmail.com) through google admin sdk. I just need to know is it possible or not? if it is, how should I get my authentication keys.

Best,
Majid

Comment: Shouldn't you raise this on [Developer Support](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/support)??

Comment: They want people to ask their questions here with "google-admin-sdk" tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

Within the [Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk), you'll see an option on the left, *Manage Settings*. From here, you can click on *[Email Settings](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/)*. Managing labels are specifically detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_labels) and the authorization info can be found within the [Email Settings API Authentication](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/auth) section.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not possible on an @gmail.com account. Admin SDK is for Google Apps admins only